# how to join nested dictionaries values in the sql table (Error shown : sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write the nested dictionaries into SQL Table in a single row.

I want to join the (User_ID ) Dictionary values and (V.Values()) into single row.

If I try to combine into single row, I'm getting error message like " TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found "

Since it is a nested dictionary, I don't know how to combine. I tried some methods with the help of internet but it is no use.

Does anyone can solve this issue, It would be really helpful for me.

Working code :

```
import mysql.connector as conn

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00")

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details ( User_ID VARCHAR(255), Name VARCHAR(255), Age VARCHAR(255), Occupation VARCHAR(255) ) ")

user_details = {}

while True:
    user_input = input(" You're Operation Please ( New / View ) Details : ").lower()

    if user_input == 'new':
        create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
        user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
        user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
        user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age
        user_occupation = input(" Enter the users occupation : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Occupation'] = user_occupation

        print(f" New User account {create_user_ID} has been successfully created")
        for detail in user_details.items():
            print(detail)

        for k,v in user_details.items():
            columns = ", ".join(["User_ID"] + list(v.keys()))

# I think the problem is in this for loop, could anyone suggests any solution please.

            values = ", ".join([k] + list(v.values()))
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(columns, values))
            db.commit()

        process = input(" Do you want to continue the Account creation process (YES / NO ) : ").lower()
        if process == 'no':
            break

    elif user_input == 'view':
        break

    else:
        print(" Please enter the proper command to execute (new / view)")
```

Code - Output( User-defined Values)

```
{'1101': {'Name': 'Test_User', 'Age': Test_Age, 'Occupation': 'Test_Occupation'}}
```

SQL Output (For Example)

```
User_ID  User_name    User_Age    User_Occupation

1101     Test_User    Test_Age    Test_Occupation
```

Let me know any solution for this problem.

Thanks for your time in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    values = ", ".join([str(k)] + list(v.values()))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found
```

This is because when you are asking the user for their age, you are forcing their input to be an integer. The `join` operation is a string method and so doesn't work. By removing the typecasting to an integer your script will work and your for loops are actually correct.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but If I remove the Type casting in creating table, it will create an another issue, without declaring the type we can't create columns right. And If I use "string" values for the inputs and change the column types "VARCHAR" that time also I'm getting error like "ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column ...... in 'field list' ".

Comment: What does your sql statement look like? After I remove the typecasting, i get an out put like so: `INSERT INTO Details (User_ID, Name, Age, Occupation) VALUES (1, bob, 23, builder)` which is a valid sql statement.